# Why bother requiring CSRF token on POST requests?

Tags: security, csrf

My understanding is that CSRF prevents an attacker using an `<img>` tag to get the victim's browser to send a request that would be authenticated using the session cookie. Given that `<img>`s are always submitted using a GET request, not POST, then why is it necessary to require a CSRF token in a POST request?

Also, the attacker wouldn't be able to submit a form in the webpage without being able to run code (ie. an XSS attack), in which case they can circumvent your CSRF protections anyway.

Comment: Form POST doesn't obey the same origin policy. They can host the form on *any* site.

Comment: I think your assumption that CSRF-tokens are (solely) to defeat ``<img>`` attacks is wrong. Other possible attacks are using javascript on the malicious site to send a hidden POST request to the target site or a forged form on the malicious site…

Comment: @JonasWielicki that's true (I'm still getting my head around all of this), and there's also `<iframe>` injection to be considered too. 

I'm thinking that a [token-based approach](http://blog.auth0.com/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/) will be a better solution in my case anyway.

Answer (score 6):

The attacker can host a form on their own site, but it does not require the form to be submitted by the user. They can use JavaScript to do this:

```html
<form method="post" action="http://www.example.com/executeAction">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="deleteAllUsers">
</form>

<script>document.forms[0].submit()</script>
```

IFrame injection is more of a [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) vulnerability. A XSS vulnerability is more serious than a CSRF one because more damage can be done and it will always override any CSRF protection you have. Make sure you are always correctly encoding output for the context that the output is in (e.g. encode for HTML or for JavaScript as appropriate).

Check out the [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) - their best recommendation is to use the *Synchronizer Token Pattern* which seems similar to the link in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21177163/413180) but can work in combination with cookies.

Also, here's a link to the [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).

Comment: Thanks, so another protection against this would be to check the "Origin" header to ensure that the form hasn't been submitted from another site. Do you think this would be sufficient protection?

Comment: You could simply check the `X-Requested-With` header to make sure it is `XMLHttpRequest`. This header cannot be sent cross domain (unless you have explicitly enabled it using CORS headers).

Answer (score 1):

Cross Site Request Forgery is when a site (let's say evil.example.com) can force a visiting user to make requests to another site (let's say example.com). It's not really forcing a user since embedding a image that (HTTP GET request) or POST request via form submission or javascript is not that difficult.

1. You should not make state or data changes via HTTP GET requests. img tags (get request) shouldn't be able to make any kind of change what so ever. If you allow this ... stop it. :)
2. POST requests need to contain a value that is not guessable by a remote attacker. Typically this is a per request random value.

So yes, CSRF is a a demonstrated, known vulnerability that you should bother protecting against.

Comment: Good answer, but the random value doesn't need to be per request, only per user session.

Answer (score 0):

Having done some further investigation:

It's possible for the attacker to host a `<form>` on their own site which submits to the target site (your site). All they need to do is get the victim to submit this form and it'll be submitted with their cookies and potentially their authentication.

It's also possible for the attacker to inject an `<iframe>` into your site, which would then be able to display this malicious `<form>`.

I'm thinking that a [token-based approach](http://blog.auth0.com/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/) is a better solution for my use case.