# How to implement an XSRF attack via auto-submitting form in iframe?

Tags: iframe, cross-domain, csrf

I'm working on a Single-Page App and choosing, what scheme to use for user sessions, cookie or localstorage. In particular, I'm considering CSRF attack scenario. The most reasonable CSRF attack scheme IMHO is auto-submitting a form in an invisible iframe. But how does it work?

Suppose that I'm the developer of `maliciouswebsite.net` and on my page I'm creating an invisible iframe pointing to some page at `bank.com` website with the intention to make user, visiting `maliciouswebsite.net` and logged in on `bank.com`, to unwillingly send his money to me by auto-submitting the form in an invisible iframe.

But in such case the code in iframe won't be scriptable from `maliciouswebsite.net`, because it will be considered Cross-Origin and browser won't allow javascript in the main frame of `maliciouswebsite.net` to manipulate with elements of `bank.com` invisible frame.

A different scenario is that `maliciouswebsite.net` just presents an invisible iframe with form `action=bank.com/api/transfer_money?...`. So the Origin of this iframe is still `maliciouswebsite.net`. But in such case the form won't see the user's cookie at `bank.com` and won't be allowed to do anything, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A different scenario is that maliciouswebsite.net just presents an
>   invisible iframe with form action=bank.com/api/transfer_money?.... So
>   the Origin of this iframe is still maliciouswebsite.net. But in such
>   case the form won't see the user's cookie at bank.com and won't be
>   allowed to do anything, right?

Yes, this is how it were to work should an IFrame be used.

Basically it starts off with a page with a form on that auto submits to another domain, like you say. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21182309/413180) for an example.

Then so as to not alert the user that the form is being submitted, the attacker embeds the page with that form in a hidden IFrame.

The browser will automatically send cookies, *as long as the user is already logged into `bank.com`*. Remember, the form does not need to see cookies (`maliciouswebsite.net`), only the target domain does (`bank.com`).

Comment: Ah, so, although javascript on `maliciouswebsite.net` can't access cookies related to `bank.com` domain, pure html request can force browser to send cookies, related to `bank.com`, from `maliciouswebsite.net` - that's the point of XSRF.

Comment: The first scenario with scripted auto-click is, probably, impossible. But it's possible to make iframe transparent and huge, so that the browser will interpret any user click on `maliciouswebsite.net` as click on `bank.com`'s submit button. And that's clickjacking attack, different from XSRF. We should use `x-frame-options` header to protect from it.