# Django RestFrameWork Post Request with csrf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am a newbie to django/django-rest-framework. I am experimenting with React for the frontend and Django-rest-framework for the backend. The client and server **are on different domains**. I was able to make a `GET` request, for `POST` request I also manage to do it but only with the `csrf_exempt` decorator, which is not ideally. The django documentation recommended me to use `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` to avoid `csrf verification` but that also doesn't work for me. Here's my **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'api.apps.ApiConfig',
'rest_framework',
'corsheaders',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 ]
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
'localhost:3000',
)


CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
'localhost:3000'
]
```

Should I start implementing `jwt-authentication` to avoid this situation ? What is the best approach to this problem?

Comment: What are the Django REST framework settings you are using ?

Comment: Just go through this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156400/why-bother-requiring-csrf-token-on-post-requests), its always a good idea to post with a csrf

Comment: @Linovia I am using default settings